# Python import old version package instead of new one

Tags: python, pip

I install the library 'numpy1.11.0', 'pandas0.18.1', 'scipy0.17.1' with pip into the site-packages. The problem is that when I import numpy and scipy in my project, an old version which has also been installed is imported instead of the new version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc

print(np.__version__)
print(np.__file__)

print(pd.__version__)
print(pd.__file__)

print(sc.__version__)
print(sc.__file__)

output:
1.8.0rc1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc
0.18.1
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc
0.13.0b1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/__init__.pyc
```

As only one pandas is installed, the newest version is imported correctly.

[image]

Both of the python and site-packages have numpy and scipy.

How could I fix the problem, thanks!

Comment: Are you installing with pip or brew?

Comment: yes,  the new package was installed into site-packages by pip.

Comment: Or you could uninstall the brew version of numpy and scipy--- but I think the OSx use it. I had same problem... This problem recurs everytime you to a python upgrade using brew... You are using brew, right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall all the above packages... Use brew to install the pandas. 
It should install dependencies as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), install the libraries you want in the version you want.

Comment: @itenyh Isolation environment is a best pratice. I recommend.

Comment: @Merlin why this doesn't solve the problem. Using virtualenv you would be able to use multiple versions of certain library for specific projects.

Comment: @Omar, virtualenv is a good idea, bad in practice. OP would have reinstall all new packages in EVERY virtualenv.. OP should fix the base. Virtualenv would add a layer of abstraction thats not need for the task at hand.  This a OSx specific problem.

Comment: @Merlin why is bad in practice? Lots of people uses this for development. And, I think is better to isolate dependencies for every project where you could have an specific stack with no compromising your system dependencies.

Comment: I solve my problem by simply deleting numpy and scipy on the path /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python. I think @Merlin`s answer inspired me to do this, so I accept his answer, and I also learn the basic of Virtualenv, maybe it will help in my future work. Thanks for you all!